# How do I set up Apple Mail to show me e-mail priority?

Tags: macos, mail.app

When somebody sends me an e-mail that is marked as "High priority" it does not show up any differently than other e-mails.  I am expecting to see a red flag or other indicator to show that the e-mail has been marked by the sender (which could, for instance, be my boss) as more important or urgent and in need of immediate attention.  Other e-mail clients I have used in the past did this automatically.

I have poked around a bit in the preferences and in the menus but I haven't found anything to enable such a feature.  How do I enable Apple's default mail app to show me the information in the overview of my messages? (My mail window comes up with mailboxes/folders on the left, followed by a list of e-mail summaries (sender, date, subject, and the first few words of the e-mail) to the right of that, and on the right is the actual contents of whatever message is selected.  I don't see any indication of priority anywhere.

Technical note: the sender is setting the following headers to indicate priority:

```
X-Priority: 1 (Highest)
X-MSMail-Priority: High
Importance: High
```

Comment: It used to show !! in the Flags column - doesn't seem to any more

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is to use Apple Mail's rules to customize how you want these displayed—you can make them stand out even more than a simple !! in the message list by setting up a Rule in Preferences:

[image: Screen shot of Apple Mail Preferences Rules pane]

In this case, specify that you want to apply the rule to messages with high priority. Then choose the formatting that you want. I chose to list messages with a red background. When *new* messages arrive with a high priority, they got a red background in the message list.

Comment: I don't think this behavior has changed significantly between Mountain Lion (which you asked about) and Yosemite (which is depicted in my screen shot).

Comment: It still works the same way on Mavericks 10.9.5

Comment: This does work for new messages (although why it doesn't work to apply the rule to existing messages, I don't know).  I now also see "!!" between the e-mail address and the time in the message, which I did not see before.  Just seeing the "!!" by default would be fine, since we want to deploy this solution across our organization with minimum fuss.